# Castor generate BigDecimal type for integer type in xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, castor

I use xsd schema like :

```
<xsd:element name="TrxIdRs" type="TrxIdRs_Type"/>
<xsd:complexType name="TrxIdRs_Type">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
            <xsd:attribute ref="trxStatusCode" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute ref="trxStatusDescr" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:attribute name="trxStatusCode" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:attribute name="trxStatusDescr" type="xsd:string"/>
```

meaning XML like :

```
<TrxIdRs trxStatusCode="1" trxStatusDescr="descr">
    111000111
</TrxIdRs>
```

But Castor generate only BigDecimal type for this schema :

```
public abstract class TrxIdRs_Type implements java.io.Serializable {
  //--------------------------/
 //- Class/Member Variables -/
//--------------------------/
/**
 * internal content storage
 */
private java.math.BigDecimal _content;
/**
 * Field _trxStatusCode.
 */
private java.lang.Integer _trxStatusCode;
```

Is there any other variants to write xsd or configure castor to have primitive type in generated bean?

Comment: Can you add the full xsd?... where is the declaration of trxStatusCode and trxStatusDescr?

Comment: I can't show the full xsd - it's too large. Have added the attributes description and element declaration

Comment: I used Jaxb and if you change the type in xsd:decimal works fine ;)

Comment: I can't change the framework, there will be TOO MUCH changes for other xml elements. (about 2 two thousand)

Comment: Try using xsd:restriction in place of xsd:extension.

Comment: tried, and got an error "can't parse ~.xsd file"

Comment: If use xsd:restriction in place of xsd:extension - got an error "can't parse ~.xsd file"

Answer (score 1):

From http://castor.codehaus.org/1.2/srcgen-example.html

> Schema decimal type is mapped to a java.math.BigDecimal.

You should use a external bindings .. at this [link](https://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/15018/tutorial.doc) there is a tutorial for configuration (page 7).

Comment: What do you mean? I do not want to have an Objects type, only primitive or at least Integer, but NOT the java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: DOC describes how to set user defined java-type for *elements*. Only available config elements is : "<elementBinding name='...'>. But there are NO problems with elements. There is a problem with content of complex element (with attributes).